# I can't connect to an MQTT broker running on Docker with a Node application

Tags: node.js, docker, mqtt

I have an MQTT broker running on a Docker container:

```yaml
mqtt-broker:
    image: rabbitmq
    container_name: mqtt-broker
    ports:
        - "1883:1883"
        - "9001:9001"
```

I want to create a Node client running on the host machine, but I can't make it connect to the broker. Here is my code:

```js
const mqtt = require('mqtt');
const brokerUrl = 'mqtt://localhost:1883';
const topic = 'myTopic';

const client = mqtt.connect(brokerUrl, {
    protocol: 'tcp'
});

client.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('Error:', err);
});

client.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Connected to MQTT broker');
    client.subscribe(topic, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error subscribing to topic:', err);
        } else {
            console.log('Subscribed to topic:', topic);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is what I get:

```
Error: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) {
  errno: -104,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

I tried to set the `brokerUrl` variables to other values such as `mqtt://localhost:9001`, `mqtt://mqtt-broker:9001`, `mqtt://mqtt-broker:1883` but it has never worked. The `mqtt-broker` container is running without errors.

Comment: Have you enabled the RabbitMQ MQTT plugin? See the "Enabling Plugins" section of [the docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq). Testing with a known good app ([mosquitto_sub](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html)/[MQTTX](https://mqttx.app/) etc)) is a good way to ensure the broker is operational before testing your code.